# Use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to find .zip?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I'm new to PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser and I'm trying to list links that end in `.zip` and `-animal.jpg` but I'm not sure how to do it.

I've tried searching on google but to no avail, all I get from below is a white page.

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('<domain removed>');

// Find all -animal image files
foreach($html->find('-animal.jpg') as $element)
echo $element->href . '<br>';

// Find all zip files
foreach($html->find('.zip') as $element)
echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: In jQuery or [this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/?source=directory) you would do: `'a[href$=".zip"],a[href$="-animal.jpg"]'` - that's just css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `strpos()` to search for that particular href. Example:

```
$links = $html->find('a');
foreach($links as $link) {
    if(
        (strpos($link->href, '-animal.jpg') !== false) ||
        (strpos($link->href, '.zip') !== false)
    ) {
        echo $link->href . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the URL instead of stripping it from the output? Thanks

Comment: @ToCode i just used innertext as an example, i changed it to `->href` check my revision